# When having 2 stores, how do you add a product to a specific store using the REST API?

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I have two stores ("A" and "B"). Store "A" is selected as the default store. I want to add product "X" to store "B" using Magento 2's REST API.

I'm currently trying to do a `POST` request to `http://localhost:8888/magento/index.php/rest/V1/products` with the following JSON data:

```
{
   "product":{
      "sku":"3",
      "name":"Product X",
      "attribute_set_id":4,
      "price":1,
      "status":1,
      "visibility":4,
      "type_id":"simple"
   }
}
```

When doing this, the product gets added to the default store, which is store "A". My question is, how do I add a product to store "B" using the REST API?

I could not find anything in the [docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html#/) about how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer seems to be quite simple. All you need to do is add the store code to the URL.

Example URL:
`http://localhost:8888/magento/index.php/rest/{store_code}/V1/products`

Comment: I created custom API to update details but I want to update detail based on store code and store code is collected from payload any idea?